# why mycode after for loop is not executed?

Tags: php

please check my code. i have some program to return the third largest word in a given array.
if in the third largest word has a same letters long, so retrun the last one.

for example `['world', 'hello', 'before', 'all', 'dr']` the output should be `'hello'`.

my program is working fine, however when I want to `echo` the `$result`, the code doesn't execute.

here is my code:

```
<?php
$array = ['world', 'hello', 'before', 'all', 'dr'];

$array2 = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $array2[$value] = strlen($value);
}
asort($array2);
$slice = array_slice($array2, -3);

$array3 = [];
foreach ($slice as $key => $value) {
    $array3[] = $key;
}

$result = "THIS RESULT SHOULD BE RE ASSIGNED, BUT WHY !!!!!";
for ($i = count($array3) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $result = $array3[$i];
        return $result;
    }
    if (strlen($array3[$i]) == strlen($array3[$i - 1])) {
        $result = $array3[$i];
        return $result;
    }
}
echo "THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING";
echo $result;
```

Comment: You have `return` statements in the loop.

Comment: Do you mean `break` instead of `return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use break instead of return.

```
<?php
$array = ['world', 'hello', 'before', 'all', 'dr'];

$array2 = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $array2[$value] = strlen($value);
}
asort($array2);
$slice = array_slice($array2, -3);

$array3 = [];
foreach ($slice as $key => $value) {
    $array3[] = $key;
}

$result = "";
for ($i = count($array3) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $result = $array3[$i];
        break;
    }
    if (strlen($array3[$i]) == strlen($array3[$i - 1])) {
        $result = $array3[$i];
        break;
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the return statements in the loop. instead of return, perhaps use break.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way as well.

```
<?php 
/**
 *  Read more about here
 *  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
 */
function sort_by_length($a,$b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}
$array =['world', 'hello', 'before', 'all', 'dr'];
usort($array,'sort_by_length'); // sorting array with a custom function.

if(count($array) >= 2) {    
    $sliced = array_slice($array, 2);    
    $result = $sliced[0];
    /**
     *  Read more at 
     * 1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php
     * 2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php
     */
    while(strlen(current($sliced)) == strlen(next($sliced))){
        $result = current($sliced);
    }
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "Not enough items in array.";
}
```

This will output

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` .It return the value so any code after it will not be executed.